# BindingSource Get Current Row

Tags: c#, datasource, generic-list, bindingsource

I cannot get current row value. How can i do?

> ```
> bindingSource1.DataSource = LData; (LData is Generic List)
> ```

```
public DataRow currentRow
    {
        get
        {
            int position = this.BindingContext[bindingSource1].Position;
            if (position > -1)
            {
                return ((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot get current row with :

```
    MessageBox.Show(currentRow["NAME"].ToString());
```

Getting Err: InvalidCastException, how can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't expect to have `DataRow` objects in `bindingSource1.Current` if you're setting `DataSource` to a `List<T>` instead of to a `DataTable`. In your case `bindingSource1.Current` will contain an instance of the generic type.

I suppose you're initializing LData like this:

```
LData = new List<T>();
```

The property should then look like this:

```
public T currentRow
{
    get
    {
        int position = this.BindingContext[bindingSource1].Position;
        if (position > -1)
        {
            return (T)bindingSource1.Current;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And you could read the value like this (assuming `Name` is a property of `T`):

```
MessageBox.Show(currentRow.Name);
```

Not tested of course, but something like this should work. Use the debugger in the following line to see what the contents of the `Current` property are actually like:

```
return (T)bindingSource1.Current;
```